# Oracle 9i database Import issues

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, dmp

Please help with my oracle 9i Database Recovery.

I was working on rebuilding database using dmp file. I was dropping tablespaces and recreating tablespaces for this scenario, This will work for first few instances and then its stops importing data and throws imp-00015 error saying `"Following statement failed because the object already exists"` and I did noticed it wasn't listing all tablespaces. Please help how I can avoid this as I want to run this on daily basis to migrate data from parent to child database.

Comment: I found a work around for this. I took a suggestion from my manager and dropped all tables before dropping  tablespaces and this helped my succesful import with out any errors and I did scheduled this as  daily migration and so far it was smooth. Hope its helps some one. Thank you for your support NorthCat